Fjord Explorer – a Nagareru crossword
This is part 72 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a Nagareru puzzle. Draw a single, non-intersecting, directional loop in the grid connecting centres of cells horizontally and vertically. The loop must pass straight through all black arrows in the grid, with the arrow indicating the direction of the loop. White arrows indicate directions where “wind” is blowing. Each white arrow applies to every white cell it sees directly, all the way up to the first black cell or the border of the grid, in the direction of the arrow. Whenever the loop enters a stretch of cells affected by a wind, it must immediately turn in the direction of the wind. After that it may turn away or continue straight, but never go against the direction of the wind. The circles in the grid are not relevant to the Nagareru or the associated crossword; they’re simply there to help you find the final answer in the end.
Today I have snorkelled with dolphins in pristine blue waters and hiked up a mountain side to enjoy a spectacular view of sand-covered fjords. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.

Crossword on Penpa+
Nagareru on Penpa+
Across
1. Econ. activity indicator
4. Given english, perhaps
8. Tycoon
13. Meadow
14. — colada
15. Montoya of The Princess Bride
16. Restrooms, for short
17. Unmodified
18. Sounds of dismay or relief
19. Racy material
21. In addition
23. City home to the 50 of 18
24. Inclined
28. A barque often has three
31. Walther PPK, for one
32. City near Düsseldorf
35. Quarreled
37. Old French coin
38. Unfortunately
39. — of London, former prison
40. Source of inspiration
41. Stimpy's pal
42. Recluse
43. Loosened
44. Landlord
46. Structural overhaul, for short
48. — flu, early 1900s pandemic
50. Card game for four players
54. Particle no longer considered "indivisible"
55. Saves
56. Zinfandel or Gewürztraminer, say
59. Axe target?
61. Tattoo parlor necessities
62. Old Roman diviner
63. Pixar clownfish
64. "Yikes!"
65. Parts of a how-to guide
66. Irish valley
67. He chose the red pill
Down
1. Stink eye
2. County in England's southwest
3. Hobbies
4. Parking lot units
5. City home to the 24 39A
6. Brown or Rice, e.g.
7. Like M or N, phonetically
8. Stated incorrectly
9. Know one's — (be knowledgeable)
10. Concert
11. "Not this again!"
12. — Alamos
16. Bulgarian currency
20. "I think —, I think —"
22. Pariah
25. Group response to "Who's there?"
26. An Old West sheriff would have known how to tie one
27. — to one's seat
29. 1982 sci-fi classic
30. One who scatters (e.g. seeds)
32. Noblemen
33. Power menu option
34. Sophie Turner's role in Game of Thrones
36. "Those — the days!"
39. Belvedere —, partly conserved statue
40. Child's birthday party entertainment, perhaps
42. Dawdles
43. Blunders
45. Grab
47. Shakespearean fairy king
49. Asian people featured in Gran Torino
51. — cap
52. Gordon who thought "greed is good"
53. Suffix for baron or priest
55. City home to the 48 65
56. Greenhouse —
57. Monotonous routine
58. Basis of movie theater restrictions
60. Ctrl-alt-—

Gladys will return in Otherworldly.

Gladys is in:

 MUSANDAM, Oman, a peninsula known as the "Norway of Arabia" for its fjords, where dolphins can be seen.

The crossword solves as follows:

 

Clue explanations:

 Across:
 1. Econ. activity indicator GDP
 4. Given english, perhaps SPUN
 8. Tycoon MOGUL
 13. Meadow LEA
 14. PINA colada
 15. Montoya of The Princess Bride INIGO
 16. Restrooms, for short LAVS
 17. Unmodified AS IS
 18. Sounds of dismay or relief SIGHS
 19. Racy material EROTICA (no hyperlink provided!)
 21. In addition ALSO
 23. City home to the [BRIDGE] of [SIGHS] VENICE
 24. Inclined LEANING
 28. A barque often has three MASTS
 31. Walther PPK, for one PISTOL
 32. City near Düsseldorf ESSEN
 35. Quarreled ROWED
 37. Old French coin SOU
 38. Unfortunately ALAS
 39. TOWER of London, former prison
 40. Source of inspiration MUSE
 41. Stimpy's pal REN
 42. Recluse LONER
 43. Loosened EASED
 44. Landlord LESSOR
 46. Structural overhaul, for short REORG. (short for 'reorganisation')
 48. SPANISH flu, early 1900s pandemic
 50. Card game for four players BRIDGE
 54. Particle no longer considered "indivisible" ATOM
 55. Saves RESCUES
 56. Zinfandel or Gewürztraminer, say GRAPE
 59. Axe target? ODOR (Axe, as in the body fragrance brand name - 'Lynx' in the UK)
 61. Tattoo parlor necessities INKS
 62. Old Roman diviner AUGUR
 63. Pixar clownfish NEMO
 64. "Yikes!" ACK
 65. Parts of a how-to guide STEPS
 66. Irish valley GLEN
 67. He chose the red pill NEO

Down:
 1. Stink eye GLARE
 2. County in England's southwest DEVON
 3. Hobbies PASTIMES
 4. Parking lot units SPACES
 5. City home to the [LEANING] [TOWER] PISA
 6. Brown or Rice, e.g. UNI
 7. Like M or N, phonetically NASAL
 8. Stated incorrectly MISSAID
 9. Know one's ONIONS (be knowledgeable)
 10. Concert GIG
 11. "Not this again!" UGH
 12. LOS Alamos
 16. Bulgarian currency LEV
 20. "I think I CAN, I think I CAN"
 22. Pariah LEPER
 25. Group response to "Who's there?" IT'S US
 26. An Old West sheriff would have known how to tie one NOOSE
 27. GLUED to one's seat
 29. 1982 sci-fi classic TRON
 30. One who scatters (e.g. seeds) SOWER
 32. Noblemen EARLS
 33. Power menu option SLEEP
 34. Sophie Turner's role in Game of Thrones SANSA (Stark)
 36. "Those WERE the days!"
 39. Belvedere TORSO, partly conserved statue
 40. Child's birthday party entertainment, perhaps MAGICIAN
 42. Dawdles LOITERS
 43. Blunders ERRS
 45. Grab SNAP UP
 47. Shakespearean fairy king OBERON (A Midsummer Night's Dream)
 49. Asian people featured in Gran Torino HMONG
 51. DUNCE cap
 52. Gordon who thought "greed is good" GEKKO (Wall Street)
 53. Suffix for baron or priest -ESS
 55. City home to the [SPANISH] [STEPS] ROME
 56. Greenhouse GAS
 57. Monotonous routine RUT
 58. Basis of movie theater restrictions AGE
 60. Ctrl-alt-DEL

The nagareru resolves like so:

 

Logical steps as follows...
Step 1:

 First, draw the lines straight through each of the black arrows in the puzzle, adding corners where obviously required.



 Now note the following points of logic:

 a) The loop needs a way to get in and out of the bottom leftmost section.
 b) The loop has entered the top middle section and so needs a way to exit it.
 c) The loop cannot pass from R6C7 to R6C6 because of the wind marker above.
 d) The loop cannot pass from R8C2 to R8C3 because the directions of the two linked arrows would contradict each other. The loop must therefore pass from R8C1 to R8C2 to satisfy the wind marker to its left. The whole of the middle-left section then resolves itself due to knock-on deductions.



Step 2:

 The loop cannot pass from R14C5 to R14C4, else the wind blowing from below would leave a loop segment stranded in the bottom-left section. There is therefore only one way to resolve this section - by heading to the bottom row before turning in the wind.

 Furthermore, the loop cannot pass from R6C4 to R6C5, or a segment will be stranded in the top left section. Knock-on deductions leave only one way to complete that section.



 In the top-middle section the wind affects the loop end currently in row 2. There is only one way to navigate this.

 Furthermore, in the bottom-right section it is impossible to use the bottom row for our clockwise-moving loop because of the wind. The other wind running from the top helps to sculpt the only way a loop can be completed in this section.



Step 3:

 To navigate through the bottom-middle section and its two north-blowing winds, the loop cannot pass immediately left from R13C10 and must instead lead right to the bottom row of that column before passing leftwards in two steps.

 Once it reaches R12C7 it cannot pass immediately left because of the wind blowing from above and must go one step further upwards before being forced to connect with the segment in the bottom-left...



 In the middle section, to satisfy the wind icon in the black square R5C7, this loop section must pass down to R9C7 and connect to the right.



Step 4:

 For the loop to connect between the top-middle and central sections, it must pass from R4C9 all the way across to R4C12 before navigating the two breezes below it, and thus the loop is complete:



Overlaying both now reveals some crossword grid letters that are circled and also fall on the loop path.

 Starting with the 'M' in R6C4 and following clockwise, this spells out MUSANDAM, our destination!



